# how to extract particular attribute from xml file using c#?

Tags: c#, .net

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            WebClient _httpReq = new WebClient(); // to talk to the web only for get method
            string response = _httpReq.DownloadString("https://open-ic.epic.com/FHIR/api/FHIR/DSTU2/Patient?family=Argonaut&given=Jason");
Console.WriteLine(response);\\prints the xml string fetched from FHIR provider EPIC
            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.LoadXml(response); // suppose that myXmlString contains "<Names>...</Names>"

            XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/entry/resource/patient/name");
// here code is trying to extract the name attribute
            foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
            {
                string firstName = xn["family value"].InnerText;
                string lastName = xn["given value"].InnerText;
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} {1}", firstName, lastName);
              //print the first name and last name of the patient
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

Comment: And what exactly is your problem?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using LINQ to XML instead of XmlDocument - it's a much nicer API.

Answer (score 1):

i do it like this:

```
XmlDocument MyDocument = new XmlDocument();
MyDocument.Load("...");

XmlNode MyNode = MyDocument.SelectSingleNode("/Node_Name");

foreach (XmlAttribute MyAttribute in MyNode.Attributes)
{
    if (MyAttribute.Name == "Attribute_Name")
    {
        object Value = MyAttribute.Value;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Review [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp). Once you start understanding it, you will find it efficient and easier to code than iterating through lists. It also lets you directly get the nodes/attributes you want.

Then the code would be something similar to

```
string attrVal = doc.SelectSingleNode("/entry/resource/patient/@name").Value;
```

Or you can Load XML in XMlDocument and You can fetch element and out of that element you can read specific atairbute,

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<reply success=\"true\">More nodes go here</reply>");

XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;

string s = root.Attributes["success"].Value;
```